# Function in python on different lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I am writing a function that returns the lenght of the sting given in input, the number of spaces, the numper of punctuation signs and so on... what can i do if i want to see the output on different lines?

**Expected output:**

```
'Number of characters: 17
Number of spaces: 4
Number of punctuation sigs: 1'
```

**Actual output:**

```
'Number of characters: 17 Number of spaces: 4 Number of punctuation sigs: 1'
```

this is the 'return' part of the code:

```
return 'length= '+str(len(s))+'number of letters= '+str(number_of_letters)
```

and so on

(I know that using print and '\n' it would be easier, but I have to use the return and i want to understand if there is a way to do that without using print + newtab)

Comment: insert into your format string `\n` wherever you want a line break (or possibly `\r\n` if you're using winderp). Separate print calls would work as well btw.

Comment: *"Actual output"* of which code? Please edit your question to include complete minimal code so we can help you.

Comment: String concatenation with `+` is kind of BASIC style. There are different options to use a format string. If you use a current version of Python you can use an f-string: `return f'length={len(s)}\nnumber of letters={number_of_letters}'`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\n` in your return statement but then you should call your function inside `print` statement.

```
def ret(input):
    return str(len(input)) + '\n''Glowing'

ret('Light')
>>> '5\nGlowing'

print (ret('Light'))
>>> 5
    Glowing
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this helpful to you?

```
return 'length= '+str(len(s))+ '\n' + 'number of letters= '+str(number_of_letters)
```